# Idioma de AutocomPlete Google

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places

Mi problema es que estoy intentando devolver una dirección sugerida con el AutoComplete de Google Places. Como mi navegador está configurado en español, y el select de los países (es el input con el que cargo el país en un formulario) está en inglés, muchos países que no matchean con la comparación aunqeu sean el mismo (Spain y España, por ejemplo).

Alguno sabe como hacer para indicarle al Autocomplete que no importa el idioma del navegador, que las comparaciones las pase siempre al inglés?

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#maps_http_places_autocomplete_amoeba-txt) con language=es, también puedes ocupar region=es para especificar el país, así acota los resultados

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=spain&region=es&language=eso&types=establishment&key=___________

Comment: Ahi estoy viendo. Gracias!!!!